# Matlab symbolic limit returns piecewise function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, symbolic-math, limits

I have a function `f` which I am trying to take the symbolic limit of. So I start with the standard

```
R1 = 18;
h1 = 6.48528;

R2 = 1.8;
h2 = 0.060045431;

f1 = R1^2 / (4 * h1);

R3 = 1;

syms x

f1 =@(r) (h2/R2^2) * r.^2 + f1;
f2 =@(r) (h2/R2^2) * r.^2 + f1; 

f1p = matlabFunction(diff(f1(x)));
f2p = matlabFunction(diff(f2(x)));

f   =@(r1, t1, r2, t2) ...
        -((r1.*r2.*(-f1(r1) + f2(r2) + (r1 - r2.*cos(t1 - t2)).*f1p(r1)).* ...
        sqrt(((1 + abs(f1p(r1)).^2).*(1 + f1p(r1).^2))./(1 + abs(cos(t2).* ...
        f2p(r2)).^2 + abs(sin(t2).*f2p(r2)).^2)).*(-f1(r1) + f2(r2) + ...
        (-r2 + r1.*cos(t1 - t2)).*f2p(r2)).*sqrt(1 + f2p(r2).^2))./ ...
        (pi.*(1 + abs(cos(t1).*f1p(r1)).^2 + abs(sin(t1).*f1p(r1)).^2).* ...
        (r1.^2 + r2.^2 + abs(f1(r1) - f2(r2)).^2 - 2.*r1.*r2.*cos(t1 - t2)).^2))
```

then I try to take the limit of `f`

```
syms r1 r2 t1 t2
limit(f(r1, t1, r2, t2), r2, r1)
```

And I get `piecewise([r1 == 0, 0], [r1 ~= 0, (limit(` huge function of r1, r2, t1, t2 `)])`

So why does Matlab not want to do the limit and is it valid to just convert to a string remove the limit and replace `r2` with `r1` the return to a function handle? Is there a better way to do this?

And I want to do this so I can then convert the entire mess back into an anonymous function (using `matlabFunction`).

Comment: The code works perfectly fine for me. As well as converting the result back to a function handle. Matlab 2014b, OSX10.10.

Comment: Hm, I got 'Warning: Function 'limit' is not verified to be a valid MATLAB function. 
> In symengine (line 57)
  In sym/matlabFunction>mup2mat (line 348)
  In sym/matlabFunction>mup2matcell (line 336)
  In sym/matlabFunction (line 156) '

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why are you trying to take the limit of a function that doesn't appear to be completely symbolic? Your `f` includes `f1p` and `f2p` that use `matlabFunction` to convert to numeric function handles. `f` itself should really be a `symfun` rather than a function handle. You comment doesn't help -what did you change to cause a warning to start occurring? If the warning was already there, then you should edit your question to include it in its entirety. Lastly, you're defining your four parameters at the top as doubles. It might help to work fully in symbolic math.